# Add specific product to cart if coupon is applied WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, merge, cart, coupon

I want to build the following:

A landingspage with a `Apply Coupon` field.
If the `coupon` is valid it needs to add a specific `product` to the cart.
So basically the coupon needs to be attached to a specific product. (in this case `product_id 99`.

I found this somewhere:

```
function wc_ninja_apply_coupon( $coupon_code ) {
    if ( 'JLSDFO' === $coupon_code ) {
        $product_id = 99;
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'wc_ninja_apply_coupon' );
```

But this is for one coupon specific. I want to add for example 1000 coupons which are merged with this product. The customer can select this product on the back-end while adding this coupons. So when the user enters one of the 1000 coupons it understands to add for example `product_id 99` to the cart.

Comment: Hey do you want to add only `product id 99` if any of the coupon code used

Comment: No, basically when adding a coupon I want to attach a product to it. So for example when creating coupon `JLSDF0` I want to have a field where I can select which product is need to be added to the cart when applying this coupon.So it is variable.

Comment: Gratuitous self-promotion, but I wrote a plugin that adds a product when a coupon is entered: https://woocommerce.com/products/free-gift-coupons/